# Is it possible to invoke the "Apply" button programmatically in the Control Panel?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, windows-8.1, windows-10

Lots of registry changes require you to logoff an logon again to apply the changes. However, if you press the `Apply` button in the `Appearance and Personalisation` section, the appearance refreshes without needing to log out:

[image: Apply Button]

I wonder if Windows provides an API for this function so that it can be called programmatically without signing out?

It would be much easier to test some settings if one could just run a simple console application or a PowerShell script to commit the changes.

Comment: One way I can imagine is by using UI automation.

Comment: You may want to look at what the button is actually doing, instead of trying to click it. It may be sending out a simple settings changed message which wouldn't be too hard to do with p/invoke and send message.

Comment: @RonBeyer I guess this would be too easy... or I don't know how to do it yet. The `*.cpl` files cannot be decompiled (not .NET) and the `ProcessMonitor` doesn't seem to be able to log windows messages, does it?

Answer (score 3):

If these is a documented way to change the setting using an API you should prefer that over changing the registry directly. For many settings you can use the [`SystemParametersInfo` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947.aspx).

Assuming that doesn't do the trick, you could use the same way to notify applications that something has changed: It broadcasts a [`WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725497.aspx). Many applications listen for that message and reload their settings when they receive it.

A quick search turned up a C# version of this broadcast: [c# Registry - commit changes on the MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/44d5a9b7-e460-4bc0-80b3-bb283ebe1e5f/c-registry-commit-changes)

```
SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, (UIntPtr)0, "Environment", SendMessageTimeoutFlags.SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 5000, out result);
```

Comment: I'll try it out later and see whether the `Please wait...` screen appears.

Comment: I used the registry key for `WindowMetrics` in the call an the only application that procmon recorded handling this message was JDownloader ;-) I guess I'll need to catch all messages sent from the Display window (if possible) and see what it does if it uses any messages for this. I was hoping there would be a magic call to some ReloadSomeRegistrySettings API that would do the trik.